# Using wsgi.py correctly in Django

Tags: python, django, wsgi, gunicorn

When I deploy my Django site I'm a little confused about the `wsgi.py` file and how locally it is used vs in production with Gunicorn.

Locally I have this file structure.

```
demo/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
manage.py
```

Settings.py has the following setting...`WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo.wsgi.application'`

However once I deployed the app running on Gunicorn I get an error saying it could not find the `wsgi.py` file, in order to get it to work I have to create the file again like this...

```
demo/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
manage.py
wsgi.py
```

This now works but it suggests to me that Gunicorn ignores the `WSGI_APPLICATION` setting in Djangos setting file `demo/settings.py`, right? If so, where does Gunicorn get its own reference to the location for the wsgi.py file and what is different locally?

This is my Gunicorn setup incase that matters...

```
[program:gunicorn_process]
command=gunicorn wsgi:application -c /srv/test/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/srv/test
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:8001"
workers = 3
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Gunicorn ignores the `WSGI_APPLICATION` setting. This setting is only used to specify the wsgi application that the `runserver` command uses.

Gunicorn does not know anything about Django, but you can specify in which module Gunicorn should look for the application. Right now it looks for an `application` attribute in the `wsgi` module:

```
command=gunicorn wsgi:application ...
```

To use the file in `demo/`, you must specify the full module path in the Gunicorn command:

```
command=gunicorn demo.wsgi:application ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that now make sense. I assume that the ``directory`` setting in the same file is how the ``gunicorn_process`` knows how to look for wsgi.py in the root of /srv/test